# removing html tags from a free flowing text to form separate sentences

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I want to extract sentences from a large piece of text. My text is something like tihs -

```
<ul><li>Registered Nurse in <font>Missouri</font>, License number <font>xxxxxxxx</font>, <font>2017</font></li><li>AHA Advanced Cardiac Life Support (ACLS) Certification <font>2016-2018</font></li><li>AHA PALS - Pediatric Advanced Life Support 2017-2019</li><li>AHA Basic Life Support 2016-2018</li></ul>
```

I want to extract proper sentences from above text. So expected output will be a list

```
['Registered Nurse in Missouri, License number xxxxxxxx, 2017',
'AHA Advanced Cardiac Life Support (ACLS) Certification 2016-2018',
'AHA PALS - Pediatric Advanced Life Support 2017-2019',
'AHA Basic Life Support 2016-2018']
```

I used python inbuilt `HTMLParser` module to strip htmls from text like above. Here is my code.

```
class HTMLStripper(HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.reset()
        self.strict = False
        self.convert_charrefs= True
        self.fed = []

    def handle_data(self, chunk):
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        self.fed.append(chunk.strip())

    def get_data(self):
        return [x for x in self.fed if x]


def strip_html_tags(html):
    try:
        s = HTMLStripper()
        s.feed(html)
        return s.get_data()
    except Exception as e:
        # Remove html strings from the given string
        p = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
        return p.sub('', html)
```

It gives the following result on calling `strip_html_tags` function on the above text (which is infact the output it should produced by its current implementation)

```
['Registered Nurse in', 'Missouri', ', License number', 'xxxxxxx', ',', '2017', 'AHA Advanced Cardiac Life Support (ACLS) Certification', '2016-2018', 'AHA PALS - Pediatric Advanced Life Support 2017-2019', 'AHA Basic Life Support 2016-2018']
```

I cannot make a strict check on `<ul> or <li> tags` as different texts may have different html tags. I there a way to split the texts like above on outer `html-tags` rather than doing a split on every `html-tag` encountered

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', line) for line in html.split('</li><li>')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much deliberation I am posting my solution here. It works pretty fine for various example I had. The approach of using `BeautifulSoup` will work if I know the tags from which text has to be extracted in advance (so that I can apply `soup.findAll(specific_tag)`), buts that's not the case with me. Also their can be multiple tags from where I have to extract text. For example -

```
<p>Science</p><div> Biology </div><div>Generation of mature T cells from human hematopoietic stem and progenitor cells in artificial thymic organoids. <span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\">Nature Methods</span> 2017,</div>
```

I the example above I want to extract texts from both `<p>` tag and `<div>` tag.

I modified the above code to handle such scenarios-

```
import re
import copy
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from sample_htmls import *

class HTMLStripper(HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.reset()
        self.strict = False
        self.convert_charrefs= True
        self.feeds = []
        self.sentence = ''
        self.current_path = []
        self.tree = []
        self.lookup_tags = ['div', 'span', 'p', 'ul', 'li']

    def update_feed(self):
        self.tree.append(copy.deepcopy(self.current_path))
        self.current_path[:] = []
        self.feeds.append(re.sub(' +', ' ', self.sentence).strip())
        self.sentence = ''

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag in self.lookup_tags:
            if tag == 'li' and len(self.current_path) > 0:
                self.update_feed()
            self.current_path.append(tag)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag in self.lookup_tags:
            self.current_path.append(tag)
            if tag == self.current_path[0]:
                self.update_feed()

    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.sentence += ' ' + data

    def get_tree(self):
        return self.tree

    def get_data(self):
        return [x for x in self.feeds if x]
```

Running the code on above example

```
parser = HTMLStripper()
parser.feed(mystr)
l1 = parser.get_tree()
feed = parser.get_data()
print(l1)
print("\n", mystr)
print("\n", feed)
print("\n\n")
```

and the output -

```
[['ul'], ['li', 'li'], ['li', 'li'], ['li', 'li'], ['li', 'li'], ['ul']]

<ul><li>Registered Nurse in <font>Missouri</font>, License number <font>xxxxxxxx</font>, <font>2017</font></li><li>AHA Advanced Cardiac Life Support (ACLS) Certification <font>2016-2018</font></li><li>AHA PALS - Pediatric Advanced Life Support 2017-2019</li><li>AHA Basic Life Support 2016-2018</li></ul>

['Registered Nurse in Missouri , License number xxxxxxxx , 2017', 'AHA Advanced Cardiac Life Support (ACLS) Certification 2016-2018', 'AHA PALS - Pediatric Advanced Life Support 2017-2019', 'AHA Basic Life Support 2016-2018']
```

Also works well on mixed tags html strings-

```
[['p', 'p'], ['div', 'div'], ['div', 'span', 'span', 'div']]

<p>Science</p><div> Biology </div><div>Generation of mature T cells from human hematopoietic stem and progenitor cells in artificial thymic organoids. <span style="text-decoration: underline;">Nature Methods</span> 2017,</div>

['Science', 'Biology', 'Generation of mature T cells from human hematopoietic stem and progenitor cells in artificial thymic organoids. Nature Methods 2017,']
```

Will love to see a corner case so that I can improve the text extraction logic.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use tools that can already parse html efficiently? Like `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

demo = '<ul><li>Registered Nurse in <font>Missouri</font>, License number <font>xxxxxxxx</font>, <font>2017</font></li><li>AHA Advanced Cardiac Life Support (ACLS) Certification <font>2016-2018</font></li><li>AHA PALS - Pediatric Advanced Life Support 2017-2019</li><li>AHA Basic Life Support 2016-2018</li></ul>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(demo, 'lxml')
sentences = [item.text for item in soup.findAll('li')]
```

the variable `sentences` now holds exactly what you wanted, test it yourself

Following your comment, I would use this code:

```
text_without_tags = soup.text
```

So now you have no more tags to worry about, just a simple string, which you can then turn to a list with `split(',')` on commas for example (but if the text is not always with commas or dots, I wouldn't bother, just use the string itself)

Note: without some known structure to the text it's impossible to always parse it the same way and get a known result. This known structure could be certain html tags, but also certain text features that you know in advance

Comment: Its not necessary that the text contain a specific tag (li in this case). Also its not necessary that the text will be a well formed html.